# How to convert some code Python2 to Python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, code-conversion

I'm working with animation in my game, but I've got an error.. Can you help me pls?)

Or do I need to add all of my code?

```
class Animation:
    def __init__(self, x, y, sprites=None, time=100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sprites = sprites
        self.time = time
        self.work_time = 0
        self.skip_frame = 0
        self.frame = 0

    def update(self, dt):
        self.work_time += dt
        self.skip_frame = self.work_time // self.time
        if self.skip_frame > 0:
            self.work_time = self.work_time % self.time
            self.frame += self.skip_frame
            if self.frame >= len(self.sprites):
                self.frame = 0

    def get_sprite(self):
        return self.sprites[self.frame]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zyzz\Desktop\game\bin.py", line 210, in <module>
    target.update(dt)
  File "C:\Users\Zyzz\Desktop\game\bin.py", line 98, in update
    self.skip_frame = self.work_time // self.time
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'module'
```

Comment: This has more to do with how you called `Animation(..)` constructors.

Comment: I need to change a name of my constructors?

Comment: Noo... It's how these are called. With the `time` parameter...

Comment: No, you need to change how you instantiate them. What are you passing as `time` when you create `Animation`? That is the `module` the error is complaining about, and it would happen regardless of Python version. Of course, it may happen that because of something elsewhere in the code, Python 3 is passing a `module` where Python 2 was passing an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

What I can see in your code it is nothing related to code in python2/python3.

Here `self.time = time` , time seems to be the imported module.
You are trying `self.skip_frame = self.work_time // self.time` where `self.work_time` is initialized with 0 earlier in `def __init__(...)`
It is trying to do operation between int(0) and a module(time) which is not acceptable.

But as per your question header if you want your code to migrate from python2.x to python3.x compatible there is a package available [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)
You can install 2to3 using `python-tools`

```
$ 2to3 example.py
$ 2to3 -w example.py # -w for write the changes back to file
```